# Polymer - class doesn't load in template?

Tags: css, polymer

I have a custom class:

```
<link rel="import" href="../bower_components/polymer/polymer-element.html">
<link rel="import" href="shared-styles.html">

<dom-module id="my-voltage">
  <template is="auto-binding">
    <div class="circle">{{volts}}</div>
    <div class="circle">{{time}}</div>
    <div class="circle">{{temp}}</div>
  </template>
  <script>
      //etc
  </script>
</dom-module>
```

In the shared-styles.html file I have the definition for the circle class:

```
  .circle {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 64px;
    height: 64px;
    text-align: center;
    color: #555;
    border-radius: 50%;
    background: #ddd;
    font-size: 30px;
    line-height: 64px;
  }
```

However, the class doesn't load. I don't get the circle around the text,  nor anything else defined there. What am I missing? Can I not use classes in templates? Do I need to import it somehow else?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm pretty sure you want something like this:

```
<link rel="import" href="../bower_components/polymer/polymer-element.html">
<link rel="import" href="shared-styles.html">

<dom-module id="my-voltage">
  <template is="auto-binding">
    <style include="shared-styles">
       /* any extra styles can go here */
    </style>
    <div class="circle">{{volts}}</div>
    <div class="circle">{{time}}</div>
    <div class="circle">{{temp}}</div>
  </template>
  <script>
      //etc
  </script>
</dom-module>
```

Note the `<style>` block.

Comment: Yep, and to see a good example, open up the iron-flex-layout-classes.html file in bower_components/iron-flex-layout/. The documentation in that file will give a great idea of how to create css classes and include them in other templates.